# List formatting apparent bug

Tags: support, markdown

On [this Sci-Fi answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/64468/143), I have three numbered headers. But instead of appearing 1, 2, 3 (as I've written in the text), they appear 1, 2, 1.

After doing some testing, I found out the if I remove this part, I get 1, 2, 3 again:

Caveat:

> Strictly speaking, Sentinel Prime did not actually *join* the Decepticons (including getting the purple badge) but he did ally himself with them and even assumed command of them (see above quote).

Here's the proof:

## OK

1. item 1
2. item 2
3. item 3

## NOK

1. item 1
2. item 2

Caveat:

> Strictly speaking, Sentinel Prime did not actually *join* the Decepticons (including getting the purple badge) but he did ally himself with them and even assumed command of them (see above quote).

3. item 3

## More testing

Test 1

1. item 1
2. item 2

Caveat:

> also happens with non-spoiler text

3. item 3

Test 2

1. item 1
2. item 2

   > does not happen when "Caveat:" is removed
3. item 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug. Markdown has specific rules in terms of lists - specifically, indentation is important. Let's take this as an example:

```
##Test 1

1. item 1
2. item 2

Caveat:
  > also happens with non-spoiler text

3. item 3
```

`Caveat` is at the same depth as the list itself, and therefore doesn't form part of an item (`item 2` in this case). More specifically, since it's at the same depth as the list, it breaks the subsequent formatting as being part of a regular paragraph. As such, subsequent items start a new list altogether, with the numbering being generically represented in your code, but defaulting to `1.` as a result of Markdown.

One space before `Caveat` adds it to the list of items:

### Test 1

1. item 1
2. item 2

   Caveat:

   > also happens with non-spoiler text
3. item 3

```
##Test 1

1. item 1
2. item 2

 Caveat:
 > also happens with non-spoiler text

3. item 3
```

Maybe your intent was to place the `Caveat` at that level. Well, then you didn't follow the rules and would require some trickery to resume your numbering:

### Test 1

1. item 1
2. item 2

Caveat:

> also happens with non-spoiler text

3. item 3

```
##Test 1

1. item 1
2. item 2

Caveat:
> also happens with non-spoiler text

3\. item 3
```

However, as you can see, now you also lose the proper formatting/indentation of the list.

Comment: Thanks Werner, fixed!

Comment: PS why is it developers always say, "it's not a bug, it's a feature"? :)