# Spoiler text fades in on Meta, instant on Sci-Fi

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, spoilers

This is a minor request - [here is some spoiler text on Sci-Fi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/64468/143). And [here is very similar text here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237373/144439).

On Meta it looks great - it fades in and then out over about half a second. On Sci-Fi it just appears.

I'm wondering if that was a conscious decision? Could we have the same cool fade in on Sci-Fi? (I haven't tested on other sites so I don't know where else it could be implemented.)

Comment: No repro for me.

Comment: @Stormblessed - right, I think it's fixed. What's the procedure? Should I ask for it to be closed as fixed or just close it myself?

Comment: I think mod-flag for no repro or status completed.