# Some markup is formatted weird on stackoverflow.com

Tags: discussion, markdown, testing

TEST 1:

```
1)
This is my first piece of text. This is my first piece of text. This is my first piece of text. This is my first piece of text. This is my first piece of text. This is my first piece of text. 
2)
This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text.
```

Renders as:

1)
This is my first piece of text. This is my first piece of text. This is my first piece of text. This is my first piece of text. This is my first piece of text. This is my first piece of text.
2)
This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text.

TEST 2:

```
1) This is my first piece of text. This is my first piece of text. This is my first piece of text. This is my first piece of text. This is my first piece of text. This is my first piece of text. 
2) This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text.
```

Renders as:

1. This is my first piece of text. This is my first piece of text. This is my first piece of text. This is my first piece of text. This is my first piece of text. This is my first piece of text.
2. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text. This is my second piece of text.

---

The above is just for testing the formatting. The *TEST 1* is clearly wrong, or is Markdown syntax that hard (to write)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List formatting apparent bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237374/282094) https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325826/282094

Comment: There is sandbox for testing, don't write new question for that. When you have conclusion what is wrong, **focus only on that**. I don't know what you mean by "clearly wrong", it's not clear to me as it looks fine to me.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard: Can you provide the link for the sandbox? (Because [Google: site:stackoverflow.com sandbox](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+sandbox) did not really help.

Comment: It is likely *3122*: *[Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formatting of *TEST 1* is within specifications. It is not the mark down that should generate a (numbered) list. Taken from the [CommonMark specification for list items](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#list-items)

> If a sequence of lines Ls constitute a sequence of blocks Bs starting with a character other than a space or tab, and M is a list marker of width W followed by 1 ≤ N ≤ 4 spaces of indentation, then the result of prepending M and the following spaces to the first line of Ls*, and indenting subsequent lines of Ls by W + N spaces, is a list item with Bs as its contents.

And what constitutes a [List](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#list):

> A list is a sequence of one or more list items of the same type.

So the `1.` is the first list item in a new list. The next line doesn't have a list marker, and it is therefore not a list item. The list ends. Instead a simple paragraph is rendered.

This behavior is similar to what can be observed on the [CommonMark playground](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus)

[image: shows dingus markdown on the left and rendered output on the right]

So, it might look *weird* for any definition of weird but it works as specified.

Comment: Was it always named "dingus"??

Comment: @Justin In the 3rd ever commit it was called that, yes: https://github.com/commonmark/commonmark.js/commit/05423ce109dd743847a62b937a89600f22b5360c

Comment: What is the gist of it? E.g., will some indent fix it (without changing the hard line breaks)?